# How can I make a single instance form (not application)?

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

In my C# application I have an option dialog that can be opened from a menu command.

I want to ensure that the option dialog have only one instance (user cannot open more than one option window at a given time) without making it modal.

Also if the user already have this window opened, and he clicks in the menu item to open it again, the app just makes the already visible form became the top most window.

Can anyone point me directions on how accomplish these tasks?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need this form as property

```
Form1 myForm = null;
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    myForm = null;
}

private void ShowForm()
{
    if (myForm != null)
    {
        myForm.BringToFront();
    }
    else
    {
        myForm = new Form1;
        myForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just declare myForm as static to be accessible by my options form FormClosed event (to make myForm = null again).

Answer (score 28):

Well, the simplest way is to have a static field which stores a reference to the single instance or null, and then a method to retrieve it or create a new one.

Note that this *isn't* the same as making it a singleton - because I assume if the form is closed, you'd want to create a new instance next time. (The alternative - hiding it and reusing it - is shown in STO's answer.) You may want something like this:

```
public class OptionsDialog : Form
{
    private static OptionsDialog openForm = null;

    // No need for locking - you'll be doing all this on the UI thread...
    public static OptionsDialog GetInstance() 
    {
        if (openForm == null)
        {
            openForm = new OptionsDialog();
            openForm.FormClosed += delegate { openForm = null; };
        }
        return openForm;
    }
}
```

You may want to make the method perform the "bring it to the front" steps as well, of course.

Comment: Hi @Jon, can you provide an example, please?

Comment: Hmm, I can see where that request came from, that's not what the post looked like originally.  Fastest gun in the West trick?

Comment: Yeah, when I posted the comment, there was no code in the post. Weird!

Comment: @RHaguiuda: There's been code there for quite a long time... it may not have had code when you *loaded* the page, but I'm sure it did before you posted the comment. No matter though ;)

Comment: It puzzles me why Microsoft don't provide some easy way in the .Net Framework to give developers the chance to easily specify "only one instance of this form to be open at any one time". Wierd.

Answer (score 11):

You need to prevent the form from closing.  If you don't, the form will be disposed and becomes unusable.  You can do this by implementing the FormClosing event:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
            this.Hide();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

To make it a singleton, just keep track of the life time of the form in your main form class:

```
    frmOptions options;

    private void btnShowOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new frmOptions();
            // To make absolutely sure:
            options.FormClosed += (o, ea) => options = null;
        }
        else {
            options.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        options.Show();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, can you explain `(o, ea) =>` I know that you set the form back to null but i dont understand this syntax

Comment: It is a lambda expression.  I'd normally write (sender, e) => but those names are already in use.

Answer (score 3):

you may use code like this:

```
private MyDialogForm _FormInstance;

public void ShowOptions()
{
     if (_FormInstance == null)
     {
        _FormInstance = new MyDialogForm();
        _FormInstance.FormClosing += (s,e) => 
        {
             e.Cancel = true;
             _FormInstance.Hide();
        }
      }
     _FormInstance.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have at least two forms. One form, call it frmMain, allows you to open frmOptions. In frmMain, add a variable of type frmOptions like this:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
     private frmOptions optionsInstance = null;
     ...
```

In the routine that opens the Options dialog, add this:

```
if (optionsInstance == null || !optionsInstance.Visible)
{
     optionsInstance = new frmOptions();
     optionsInstance.Show();
}
```

When frmOptions closes, optionsInstance will not be null, so that's why you check if it's visible before instantiating a frmOptions instance.

If this doesn't work for you, you could try a mutex, but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3087861/220039), I'm using the following code for showing a form as a modal dialog box.

```
        if (this.aboutForm == null)
        {
            this.aboutForm = new AboutForm();
            this.aboutForm.FormClosed += (sender2, e2) => { this.aboutForm = null; };
            this.aboutForm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        else
        {
            this.aboutForm.Focus();
        }
```

I have to do this because I have a menu item to display the About form in the menu of the main form, and in the context menu of the notify icon. If I open the About form using the menu of the main form, I still can open another instance by using the context menu item of the notify icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Main_Frm _main_Frm = null;

    private void Show_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_main_Frm != null)
        {
            _main_Frm .BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            _main_Frm = new Comission_Frm();
            _main_Frm .Show();
        }

         //This condition used when you closed the form the form will disposed and when you reopen.
        if (_main_Frm .IsDisposed)
        {
            _main_Frm = new _Main_Frm ();
            _main_Frm .Show();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This May Help! 
Note: The following code was taken from the article Below:
https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=150

```
static class Program
    {
        ///<summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        ///</summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            bool instanceCountOne = false;

            using (Mutex mtex = new Mutex(true, "MyRunningApp", out instanceCountOne))
            {
                if (instanceCountOne)
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Form1());
                    mtex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An application instance is already running");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```