# How to open a form only once?

Tags: c#

I have an app that show a form call System Parameters and i want the form to only pop one time so that the user cant open the same window million times. I tried

```
    private void SystemParametersClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Xpan sp = new Xpan();

            sp.CurrentItem = this.GetCaller(sender);
            if (sp.Visible==false)
            {
                sp.Show();  
            }

    }
```

It doesnt work because it is not the same instance.  :(
How do i make it only pop once?

Comment: You probably are looking for a Singleton pattern

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087841/how-can-i-make-a-single-instance-form-not-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you instantiate the form within the method? Simply instantiate it within the parent class and only call the `Show()` method within the click event.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private Xpan _Xpan;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Xpan = new Xpan();
    }

    private void SystemParametersClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Xpan.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this simple approach would suffice?

```
private bool has_been_shown = false;

private void SystemParametersClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!has_been_shown)
    {
        has_been_shown = true;
        Xpan sp = new Xpan();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First disable closing for Xpan form. You can do it by defining OnFormClosing event handler.

```
private void Xpan_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

Then define your Xpan form as a class member of the parent form, e.g.:

```
private readonly Xpan _sp = new Xpan();
```

And finally defile your Click handler this way:

```
private void SystemParametersClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_sp.Visible)
    {
        _sp.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        _sp.Activate();
    }
}
```

That's it.