# Allow the number of forms with a button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have This "HOME" as the main form ...and i have the admin login button which opens the admin login form...but the button should restrict the number of admin login form to only

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087841/how-can-i-make-a-single-instance-form-not-application

Answer (score 2):

Either show login form with `ShowDialog()` -> this will block rest forms as long as login form is visible or keep track of opened forms and do nothing on button click when login form is opened.

First Example:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = new LoginForm();
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Second example:

```
private LoginForm form;

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (form != null)
    {
       if (form.Visible)
       {
           return;
       }

       form.Show();
    }
    else
    {
       form = new LoginForm();
       form.Show();
    }
}
```

Third example (with LINQ):

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(LoginForm)))
    {
        return;
    }

    var frm = new LoginForm();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Comment: +1 all solutions are correct. Sorry, didn't see that you added third example while was writing my own answer. Decided to leave it, because of shorter linq

Comment: Thou your LINQ is better/shorter than mine :) +1

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to set a `boolean flag` once you open up the form.

```
bool AdminFormOpen;

private void adminLoginBtn_click()
{
    if(!AdminFormOpen)
    {
        // Open the form.
        AdminFormOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `Admin Form`, ensure that you reset this value via a mutator method. Something like:

```
protected void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
      parentForm.setAdminFormOpen(false);
}
```

Comment: don't forget to actually set the flag after opening the form :P

Comment: Wayyy ahead of you! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) collection to check if login form is already opened instead of using boolean flag for this:

```
if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<LoginForm>().Any())
{
    var loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.Show();
}
```

Or use [Form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) to open login form as modal form.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable to signal if the form is already.