# How to know the derived class in the base class

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, inheritance, mdi

I've searched everywhere on this and can't find anyone doing anything similar. I'm quite a newbie at C# having worked 15 years with a non-object orientated language, so I hope I'm not missing something simple.

I am trying to make a standard Winform which get's inherited, so that I don't need to repeat the code I use every time (one of the joys of .Net over what I've used for years is the ability to centralize things far more).

My problem comes that I want to implement the ability to either call the derived classes as 'single instance' or 'multiple instance' when launched from the MDI and after much much searching I've almost achieved this using 'generics'. But I've got stuck with how to know which class the current form is, to pass that to the generic class to close the form.

A simplified version of my code will help understand my problem. This is my generic class designed for launching and closing the form. It determines if the Instance for T already exists, depending on if you are launching a single or multiple instance it either shows that, or creates a new instance of the form. The MDI for is passed in the launch methods to allow me to attach the new form to that.

```
public class FormLaunch<T> where T : MyBaseForm, new()
{
    public static T Instance;
    public static void LaunchultipleInstnace(FRMMDI mdi)
    {
        Instance = new T();
        Instance.MdiParent = mdi;
        Instance.Show();
        Instance.BringToFront();
    }
    public static void LaunchSingleInstance(FRMMDI mdi)
    {
        if (Instance == null) Instance = new T();
        Instance.MdiParent = mdi;
        Instance.Show();
        Instance.BringToFront();
    }
    public static void CloseInstance()
    {
        Instance = null;
    }
}
```

A 'Single Instance' version of the form is launched from the MDI using the following statement.

```
        FormLaunch<MyDerivedClass>.LaunchSingleInstance(this);
```

The problem comes that I would like to handle the closing of the form once in my base form and not have to do it every time in the derived forms. But I can't work out how to do this.

```
public partial class MyBaseForm : Form
{
    public MyBaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void MyBaseForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormLaunch<this.GetType()>.CloseInstance();
    }
}
```

But this.GetType() does not work. If I was just using this form directly rather than inheriting it I could just use

```
        FormLaunch<MyBaseForm>.CloseInstance();
```

Or if I handled the FormClosed event in every derived class then I could just use

```
        FormLaunch<MyDerivedClass>.CloseInstance();
```

But I really want to do this in a way that stops me forgetting to do this every time in the derived class... because I wrote this a few months ago and have already forgotten pretty much every time I've used it.

EDIT: My question is really, what do I pass in the place of T in

```
        FormLaunch<T>.CloseInstance()
```

This needs to refer to the derived class and I can't seem to find that. this.GetType() refers to the correct glass but does not work.

Comment: You don't need to 'close' instances in C#. You Garbage Collector does this for you. Also, it's unclear what your actual question is.

Comment: I need to set the static 'Instance' property to null when I close the form.

Otherwise when I try and open it again the 'Launch Single Instance' code will error because it finds an instance which doesn't exist any more.

Comment: I think you want to make the base class methods into an interface. Just right click on the method and select create interface.

Comment: Could you explain more ZeroPhase, I don't see what methods to change in the base class, there is only the constructor and the handler of the 'FormClosed' event. I also don't have the 'Create Interface' option available on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply subscribe to `FormClosed` in `LaunchSingleInstance()` and remove handling of close event from form itself completely:

```
public static void LaunchSingleInstance(FRMMDI mdi)
{
    if (Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = new T();
        Instance.FormClosed += (s, e) => CloseInstance();
    }
    Instance.MdiParent = mdi;
    Instance.Show();
    Instance.BringToFront();
}
```

A more direct answer - it is possible using reflection:

```
typeof(FormLaunch<>).MakeGenericType(this.GetType())
                    .GetMethod("CloseInstance")
                    .Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: That works thanks!
I don't quite understand it though as a newbie, I want to search for an explanation. Should I search for tutorials about the 'subscribe' or does it have another name I should be searching on?

Comment: Look for general information about events in C# (how to declare, subscribe and unsubscribe). I've also used an anonymous method as event handler, which is optional.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get reading up on that. I've read about events, but probably it was during the VERY steep learning curve I was on when I first started on this .Net stuff and that bit hasn't sunk in ;)
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: OK, both answers understood with some reading, and both are working :) Exactly what I needed. I think I prefer the answer of subscribing to the FormClosed event, as it appears neater to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is just to enuse the single instance of the Form is opened you can read the answer of [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087841/how-can-i-make-a-single-instance-form-not-application)

And just a pair of another points.

- You mix different things: .NET generics and inheritance.

  - `this.GetType()` returns an instance of `System.Type` class, describing the current instance class (`this`),
  - Type parameter in `GenericClass<TypeParameter>` is just a name of the concrete class in using, or a type parameter name in the generic class definition: `Generic<TParam>`
- you can't define generic Control or Form classes. The Designer is not capable to serialize them.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed that I couldn't mix this.GetType() with the name of the class, just couldn't think what else to try in that pace.

Comment: I don't have a generic Control or Form in this case, though I've done that in the past and you are right you then can't use the designer. It does work... just makes the designer useless and everything has to be done in code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that does show just what I was trying to do, it's a variant of Max's solution and works perfectly :)